# JSF2.2 Primefaces: Reload menubar from a template client

Tags: templates, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a template where my header contains a PrimeFaces Menubar, also I have internationalization implemented.

My problem is when I'm inside a template-client and change the language my Menubar is not getting update with new language. MenuBar is dynamic from database. Following is my code.

Template.xhtml

```
<div id="top" class="top">
        <h:form id="frmSessionUser">
            <p:selectOneMenu label="Lenguaje" id="drpLanguage" onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{userSessionBean.setLocale}" value="#{userSessionBean.currentLocale}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{domainsManagedBean.countries}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:menubar model="#{menubarManagedBean.menubar}" > 
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
        <ui:insert name="top"></ui:insert>
    </div>
```

My template-client is like

```
<body>
    <ui:composition template="./Layouts/generalLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="top">
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            Here I have my page content
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="bottom">
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

My setLocale event is

```
public void setLocale(ValueChangeEvent e){
  String newLocaleValue = e.getNewValue().toString();
  DomainsManagedBean domains = new DomainsManagedBean();
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : domains.getCountries().entrySet()) {
     if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getApplication().setDefaultLocale((Locale)entry.getValue()); 
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue());
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, you're saying that you don't have this problem when having everything in a single templateless page?

Comment: In a templateless page it is not working neither. Problem is when I change the language, method to populate menu (model) is not called.